# Angular 2 trigger change between separate components

Tags: angular

I'm developing Angular 2 application. I have some separate components such as: signin, signup, dashboard, navbar. And I want to see buttons "Sign In", "Sign Up" when user didn't log in and "Sign Out" when user logged in. After redirection to dashboard component I check if user logged in.

So how can I send data and trigger changes from dashboard component to navbar component?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: And what if navbar and dashboard isn't parent and children and doesn't have any relations? Can I apply this method also?

Comment: The docs describes how to use services to communicate between components. That's what you should use.